# Python, функция return

Tags: python, return

Имеется функция отрисовки дерева

```
import simple_draw as sd
def second_tree(point, angle, length, width):
    root_color = (38, 34, 26)
    if length < 4:
        return print(point)
    root_v = sd.get_vector(point, angle, length, width)
    root_v.draw(root_color)
    next_point = root_v.end_point
    next_angle = angle + sd.random_number(18, 42)
    second_tree(next_point, next_angle, length * sd.random_number(6, 9) * .1,
            round(width * sd.random_number(8, 9) * .1))
    next_angle = angle - sd.random_number(18, 42)
    second_tree(next_point, next_angle, length * sd.random_number(6, 9) * .1,
                round(width * sd.random_number(8, 9) * .1))

Print выдает:
Point(x=843, y=150)
Point(x=838, y=142)
Point(x=841, y=141) и тд
```

Каким образом можно вытащить координаты точек из функции и передать в функцию ниже?

```
def second_tree_flowers(season, point):
    if season == 'spring':
        sd.circle(point, 2, sd.COLOR_GREEN, 0)
    elif season == 'summer':
        sd.circle(point, 2, sd.COLOR_YELLOW, 0)
    elif season == 'autumn':
       sd.circle(point, 2, sd.COLOR_ORANGE, 0)
    else:
       sd.circle(point, 2, sd.COLOR_WHITE, 0)
```

Comment: Для начала уберите `print` из `return`: `return point` Затем присвойте результат выполнения функции в переменную. А эту переменную передайте во вторую функцию.

Comment: Функция second_tree с рекурсией, return там где он сейчас возвращает None, если добавляю дополнительно return после второго или третьего вызова функции, она обрывается

Comment: Какие точки нужно вернуть? Все что сейчас печатаются на экран?

Comment: А, ну тогда нужно добавлять в какой-то список это всё. Вообще логика какая-то хитрая.

Answer (score 1):

```
def second_tree(point, angle, length, width):
    root_color = (38, 34, 26)
    if length < 4:
        return [point]
    root_v = sd.get_vector(point, angle, length, width)
    root_v.draw(root_color)
    next_point = root_v.end_point
    next_angle = angle + sd.random_number(18, 42)
    p1 = second_tree(next_point, next_angle, length * sd.random_number(6, 9) * .1,
            round(width * sd.random_number(8, 9) * .1))
    next_angle = angle - sd.random_number(18, 42)
    p2 = second_tree(next_point, next_angle, length * sd.random_number(6, 9) * .1,
                round(width * sd.random_number(8, 9) * .1))
    return p1 + p2
```

И потом использовать:

```
season = ...
points = second_tree(...)
for point in points:
    second_tree_flowers(season, point)
```

Comment: Благодарю! Все точки выгрузились